# In non-dimensionalization, what does it mean when one "assumes" a quantity has been scaled relative to another quantity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis

I'm trying to replicate the results of a paper, and they use the quantity $l$ to denote the length of the recirculation zone behind a cylinder for a problem regarding fluid flow past a cylinder. Early on in the paper, they say that all lengths are scaled by the distance between two plane walls (which is constant and equal to 1), but later on, they say "we shall assume that $l$ has been scaled relative to the cylinder diameter $d$." If I don't scale $l$ by the cylinder diameter, and just take the actual length of the recirculation zone, I wind up getting matching results as the ones in the paper, but if I do, the results turn out different. My question is whether "we shall assume" is supposed to mean that one does not need to scale $l$.

Here is a link to the paper: http://booksc.org/book/20991845/ccc1e3

If you have access, here's another link: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/bifurcation-for-flow-past-a-cylinder-between-parallel-planes/E7171D05010DC795CAA96EC3BBA7B2CB

Comment: Can you reference the paper here so others can look at it and see the context?